# Modifying a member initializer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list, member-initialization

I have some code which effectively reduces to

```
#include <vector>
class A {
    std::vector<int> m_sizes;
public:
    A(std::initializer_list<int> const& sizes) : m_sizes(sizes) {}
};

class B {
    A m_a;
public:
    B(int size_front, int size_back, std::initializer_list<int> const& sizes) : m_a({ size_front, sizes, size_back }) {}
};
```

The compiler complains that no instance of `A::A` matches the argument list.
Is there some way to flatten out the `{ int, std::initializer_list<int>, int }` to a `std::initializer_list<int>` or do I have to give `A` an extra constructor to handle this situation? What if I couldn't modify the `A` class?

Comment: A `std::initializer_list` is not modifiable. This template is mostly for compiler's own use. The only way to initialize a new `std::initializer_list` is with a default constructor, producing an empty list, or with a braced constant. In this case, `A` needs another constructor that takes a `vector` parameter, and uses that to initialize `m_sizes`; then you can use that constructor. If you cannot modify the `A` class, nothing can be done. C++ doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible: `initializer_list<T>` must be constructed from a list of items of type `T`, whose count is known at compile time. Inserting an existing list in the middle does not work.

You can work around this problem by adding a constructor overload that takes a `vector<int>` directly, and *forwarding* calls to it:

```
class A {
    std::vector<int> m_sizes;
public:
    A(const std::vector<int>& sizes) : m_sizes(sizes) {}
    A(std::initializer_list<int> const& sizes) : A(std::vector(sizes)) {}
};
class B {
    A m_a;
    std::vector<int> frame(int size_front, int size_back, std::initializer_list<int> const& sizes) {
        std::vector res;
        res.push_back(size_front);
        std::copy(sizes.begin(), sizes.end(), std::back_inserter(res));
        res.push_back(size_back);
        return res;
    }
public:
    B(int size_front, int size_back, std::initializer_list<int> const& sizes) : m_a(frame(size_front, size_back, sizes)) {}
};
```

Comment: Hmmn.... I smell copy-paste mistake?.... Check the order of types of the parameters in the member function `B::frame()`, and what you passed in the *member-initialization-list* in `B`'s constructor

Comment: @WhiZTiM You are absolutely right, thank you very much!